# Why is my Upload-File POST not working using NEST.JS and Multer?

Tags: rest, file-upload, multer, nestjs

I try to make a simple file upload REST interface using NEST.JS and MULTER -- but its not working. I am able to POST a binary file *debug.log* to the URL, and I see the "Hello undefined" message, but the uploaded file neither is created at the given folder *uploads* nor it is rejected because the extension is not correct - according to the file filter.
However, no exception or error is shown.

Why is multer not working?
Why is the *@Uploadedfile() file* shown as undefined?

Thanks

```
import { Controller, Post, Request, UseInterceptors, FileInterceptor, UploadedFile, HttpCode, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { diskStorage, File } from 'multer';

const path = require('path');

const myStorage = diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads/');
    },
    limits: { fileSize: 1000000 },
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        const extension = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase()
        const mimetyp = file.mimetype
        if (extension !== '.jpg' || mimetyp !== 'image/jpg') {
            cb(new HttpException('Only images are allowed', HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE));
        }
        cb(null, true);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + '.jpg');
    }
});

@Controller('documents')
export class DocumentsController {
    @Post()
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', { storage: myStorage }))
    public async addDocument(@UploadedFile() file): Promise<any> {
        console.log("Hello " + file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have encountered the same problem

Comment: I had the same problem. use `UploadedFiles` decorator instead (note the final "s").

Comment: Did you register/import MulterModule on your respective module where your file uploaded API exists ? It would be like this /* MulterModule.register({
  dest: './yourDestFolder',
}); */

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a late reply for the person who asked this question, but the answer is for the people who will face it in the future.

First, check the nestjs [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload)

If `MulterModule` registered in the `*.module.ts` file it creates the upload directory outside of the `src` folder. which is a good practice.

```
MulterModule.register({
    dest: './upload',
});
```

If there is a need to change the destination directory use `destination: String|callback` from `DiskStorageOptions` or `dest:string` from `FileInterceptor`. For upload path use like `src/../upload` to keep the folder outside the `src` directory.

Other problems from the above code mentioned in the question:

- ***I see the "Hello undefined" message***

reason `console.log("Hello " + file);` here file is `Object` and trying concatenate with `String`.

change it to `console.log("Hello ", file);`

- ***the extension is not correct, no exception or error is shown***

  ```
   fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
       const extension = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase()
       const mimetyp = file.mimetype
       if (extension !== '.jpg' || mimetyp !== 'image/jpg') {
           cb(new HttpException('Only images are allowed', HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE));
       }
       cb(null, true);
   }
  ```

Here need to add a `return`.

Answer (score 0):

if your issue was that it console.log shows "undefined" , use swagger instead of postman, i had the same issue